# From Excel - Send Email Reminder When Criteria is met using VBA Code

Tags: vba, outlook

I had a Table having data from Row 1 to 200 and From column A to T, I need VBA code to send email reminder to multiple recipients. There are dates in the table where i had used if condition and arrived by defining a column which will return `"YES"` . Where ever `YES` appear corresponding mail(`Column K`) should be sent with corresponding subject  (`Column C`)

I am able to create define and create mail and send mail . But unable to use for loop and IF condition to match criteria and send using `.to = ""` to a list of recipients

```
Sub Sendmail()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem


Set ol = New Outlook.Application

For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row

    Set olmail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olmail
        .To = Sheet1.Cells(i, 16).Value
        .Subject = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value & Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        .Body = Range("C2").Value
        .Display
        '.send

    End With

Next

 Set ol = Nothing
 Set olmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Outlook application is opening but without mail ID's

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I would investigate is `Sheet1`.  Worksheet names of the form `SheetN` are Excel’s internal names for the worksheets.  When the first worksheets of a workbook are created, `Sheet1` is `Worksheets("Sheet1")`, `Sheet2` is `Worksheets("Sheet2")` and so on.  But once you start renaming or moving worksheets, this correspondence can be lost.  I suspect `Sheet1` is not the worksheet containing the email details.

Note: “Sheet1” is the default name for the first worksheet in English versions of Excel.  If your language is not English, the default name is probably something appropriate for your language.

If you look at the VBA Editor’s Explorer panel, you will see something like this:

```
 VBAProject (YourNameForWorkbook.xlsm)
  - Microsoft Excel Objects
      Sheet1 (YourNameForWorksheet1)
      Sheet2 (YourNameForWorksheet2)
  - Microsoft Excel Objects
      Module1
      YourNameForModule
```

The minuses are in square boxes.  If any are pluses, the group will not be expanded.  Click the plus to expand.  Is `Sheet1` the worksheet you expect?  If not, the instructions below will help.  If `Sheet1` is the worksheet you expect, we will need to look for a different cause.

If a workbook has a single worksheet, it is perhaps acceptable to leave the name as the default “Sheet1”.  I think it is always best to rename worksheets to something meaningful such as “EmailDetails”.  When you return to this workbook in six or twelve months, meaningful names make understanding the workbook much easier.

Next I would add two more statements:

```
Dim WshtEmail As Worksheet
Set WshtEmail = Worksheets("EmailDetails")
```

Finally, I would replace every `Sheet1` with `WshtEmail`.